# "Sorry Something Went Wrong" Error on Workflow Information Page

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, workflow-history

I have created a 2013 workflow in SharePoint online.  The workflow works great but when I click the hyperlink in the workflow status column to go to the workflow information page I get the "Sorry Something Went Wrong" error page.  I have recreated the workflow to try to eliminate the error but I still get it.  It was working fine two weeks ago...I don't know what changed.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though the error message is returned, the workflow is associated with the content type and runs correctly as long as the content type contains the necessary fields. Therefore, you can safely ignore this error message.

Else below two solution

**Solution 1 – Change the Require content approval settings**

According to users, Sorry, something went wrong error message can appear due to your Content approval settings. This error appears when you try to save SharePoint site as a template, and in order to fix this problem, you need to follow these steps:

Click the **Gear icon** and choose **Site settings**.
Go to Web Designer Galleries section and click on Solution.
Click the Library tab and click on Library Settings.
Now click on Versioning Settings.
Locate Content approval section and set Require content approval for submitted items to No. 
Click OK to save changes.
Save the site as a template.
After the template is successfully created, you can enable content approval again.
**Solution 2 – Publish display templates**

Users reported that this error appears if your display templates aren’t published, so be sure to publish them. According to users, uploaded display templates won’t work for non-administrators, and they’ll get Sorry, something went wrong error message. To fix this problem, make sure that display templates are published.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out someone deleted the task list associated with the workflow.  Once I recreated the workflow with an active task list it was fine.